# Can I GSON deserialize a variable name which includes a hyphen in Java?

Tags: java

I am using GSON in my app. I have the following JSON response:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "person-name": "John"
}
```

So, I am creating a class like this:

```
class Person {
    boolean success;
    String person-name;
}
```

However, I am unable to create a variable `person-name`. How can I solve this?

Comment: I know that is not a valid identifier. But in response they are returning like that way.

Comment: A very common problem - even the Google reCAPTCHA v2 API has variables with dashes.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Choose a valid Java identifier and use the [@SerializedName](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation to tell GSON the name of the corresponding JSON property:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

class Person {
    boolean success;
    @SerializedName("person-name")
    String personName;
}
```

Comment: Thank God for this! Lifesaver!!

Answer (score 7):

Just thought of sharing, if you are using Jackson, which I believe many people are, you can use:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

class Person {
    boolean success;
    @JsonProperty("person-name")
    String personName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping - as name is not allowed in java besides you can use as Person_name rather than Person-name hope this will be helpful. If you have any doubts please go through rules in identifier