# Firebase dashes in child name

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Airebase database has a variable with a "-" in it and I need to get this value into a variable in java. Java doesn't allow "-" in their variables. Is there another way around this?

Comment: Please post your database structure (in text, not image) and show what you've tried in java.

Answer (score 0):

"Choose a valid Java identifier and use the @SerializedName annotation to tell GSON the name of the corresponding JSON property..." - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35391262/6351320