# Why have i error in this code?

Tags: android

What might be the problem in below mentioned code  ?

how can I fix it?

```
public static final int num-text=0x7f0b0057;
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain your question in detail...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I write a variable name including hyphen in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35391248/can-i-write-a-variable-name-including-hyphen-in-java)

Comment: You can't have a dash character in a variable name. Change it to numText

Comment: Is it num-text or num_text?did you make any changes to it?

Comment: Do not modify R.java file manually. the R.java file is generate by IDE automatically. And the subtraction sign character can not in a variable name. So check why it occured and i suggest you try to rebuild the project to see if can fix it. the 'Rebuild Project' command is in the 'build' menu.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the `-` character in an identifier (e.g., a member name). You could use the `_` character instead:

```
public static final int num_text = 0x7f0b0057;
```

On use camelCase, as per Java's coding conventions:

```
public static final int numText = 0x7f0b0057;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change dash to underscore, dash always problem in variables for some languages

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have "-" in variable name. Probably you have change in your layout file i.e. activity_main.xml

Answer (score 0):

Do not modify R.java file manually. the R.java file is generate by IDE automatically.

And the subtraction sign character can not in a variable name.

So check why it occured and I suggest you try to rebuild the project to see if can fix it. the 'Rebuild Project' command is in the 'build' menu.